# Azure Pipeline cache with multiple packages.lock.json files

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was looking to implement cache for nuget packages in my build pipeline but the documentation only shows how to implement it in a solution that has a single packages.lock.json but in reality I have multiple packages.lock.json, 1 for each project of my solution.

I found this issue on github but apparently they didn't give a solution: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6805

Has anyone run into this problem? I would like to know how the cache will work with many projects in a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is ok to have multiple `packages.lock.json` files.** You can use the following script and **don't need to make any changes**:

```
variables:
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/packages.lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
       nuget
    path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
  displayName: Cache NuGet packages
```

The cache task will cache all the packages in multiple `packages.lock.json` files. If one of the `packages.lock.json` files is changed, the cache task will be re-executed to retrieve the latest cache.